# Checking value of multiple variables (dynamic names)

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have 160 variables named resq1, resq2, ..., resq160. Values for these are assigned manually. I would like to check if values are assigned to all of them. Is it possible to loop through values of multiple variables.

There are examples of how to create multiple variables with dynamic names, but I was unable to find solution for this problem.

This doesn't work

```
 Dim cond As Boolean = True

        Dim resq(160) As String
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To 160
            If resq(i) = "" Then
                cond = False
            End If
        Next
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2: For the example code you are creating the values  incorrectly, You would proceed as this:

```
    Dim resq(10) As String 'Set the array
    Dim cond As Boolean = True
    resq(0) = 12
    resq(1) = 10
    resq(2) = 7
    For Each item As String In resq
        If item <> Nothing Then
            'Do something with your data here
        Else
            cond = False
        End If
    Next
    If cond = True Then
        'Do something when all variables  have values
    Else
        'Do something when not all variables have values
    End If
```

Remeber that resq1 is NOT the same as resq(1), The first is a seperate variable and the 2nd is the first instance of the array called resq.

Edit: To check that all the variables have an initial value you can use this code (also slightly improved since the previous code would not go through all the variables you have set):

```
    Dim cond As Boolean = True
    Dim resq(160) As String
    For Each item As String In resq
        If item = Nothing And item <> "" Then
            cond = False
        End If
    Next
```

If you want it to also check if the value is "" you can remove the 2nd part of the if statement and just use:

```
    Dim cond As Boolean = True
    Dim resq(160) As String
    For Each item As String In resq
        If item = Nothing Then
            cond = False
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Values are asigned manually, before (let say by radio buttons, for every var) Default value is "", until value is choosen (using radio buttons). Condition is that there are no blank value for any variable. By the way, with second loop I was unable to read var values, so I don't think that code works att all.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? The code I ran has worked for  me from what I understood your requirement was. Unless I am not 100% understanding your issue. EDIT: I think I understood what you mean, Give me a minute.

Comment: I could resolve my problem with an array, so thank you. Array declared globally solves it.